# PHP Locale setting for zip code formatting

Tags: php, linux, localization, internationalization, locale

I am trying to validate post/zip codes for a very international site using the locale settings in Linux using PHP. If it works it would save me tons of time. I've checked the LC_ADDRESS settings in the installed locales and see that the pattern for validation is there for each language/market.

```
locale -c LC_ADDRESS
```

How do I access this information using PHP? localeconv() does not include any information about local address validation.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the zip code via PHP?  If so, this seems like a good questions...

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am asking. There's a lot of goodies stored in the locale, such as phone and address validation, but only some are exposed to PHP using the built in functions such as localeconv() and setlocale()

Comment: Doesn't look like anyone is responding which means to me it may not be possible.  Consider setting a bounty.

Comment: For now, I am following the advice of using http://i18napis.appspot.com/address instead. It seems very thorough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like noone actually have done this. I am guessing it would take improvements to the PHP `localeconv()` function to actually read the entire thing, and that would be a feature request to them.

In the meantime I got the advice to fetch the data from http://i18napis.appspot.com/address
and that actually contains the same information as the locale LC_ADDRESS and LC_PHONE does, so I am all good even though it means making an extra outgoing HTTP call.